# Specify multiple patterns in Select-string

Tags: powershell

I cannot properly format my select-string so that I can use mulitple patterns.  I am also trying to espcape the \'s in my pattern.  Its using a directory path.

These are the patterns I need to search for:

```
Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\DENIAL.TXT 

Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\NEWORIGIN.TXT    

Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\ORIGIN.TXT    

Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT
```

This code is working for just a single pattern search.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter FTP_Outbound*.* -Path $rootFolder| Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-.5)}| Select-String -pattern  ([regex]::Escape('Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\CFGP\TO\DENIAL.TXT'))| % {
  Copy-Item -Path $_.Path -Destination 'c:\Temp' 
}
```

In the end, I would like it to both copy the file to the C:\Temp, and display the line it found in the file within the powershell window.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
[11:18:24 PM] Begin SFTP File \\BATCH1\TO\BRRef[20190724202940].txt To BRRef.txt
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\DENIAL.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\DENIAL.TXT]
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\NEWORIGIN.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\NEWORIGIN.TXT]
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\ORIGIN.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\ORIGIN.TXT]
[11:18:48 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\BRRef[20190724202940].txt] to [\BRRef.txt]
[11:18:48 PM] Update ProducedFile Set DeliveredFileName='BRRef.txt' Where CreateID=7710395
[11:18:48 PM] Successfully backed up file as :\\BATCH1\TO_BACKUP\BRRef[20190724202940]_20190724_231848.txt
FILE #2. [Ed.TXT[20190724194428]], begin FTP at [11:19:05 PM] 
Destination file name is: Ed.TXT[20190724194428]
After replaceing [], destination file name become: Ed.TXT
[11:19:05 PM] Begin SFTP File \\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT[20190724194428] To Ed.TXT
[11:19:07 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\Ed.TXT]
[11:19:07 PM] Update ProducedFile Set DeliveredFileName='Ed.TXT' Where CreateID=7710363
[11:19:07 PM] Successfully backed up file as :\\BATCH1\TO_BACKUP\Ed_20190724_231907.TXT[20190724194428]
```

Comment: [1] please REMOVE the extra powershell tags - 2,3,4 ... only ONE should be used. if you need to run on multiple versions, then list the _lowest_ version. [2] please show some sample data AND the items you want to match AND the items you _do not_ want to match.

Comment: Sample data added to original post.  I stated earlier the strings that I want to identify.  All other lines can be ignored.  Formatting on this site always troubles me.

Comment: so you want all the lines that contain `Successfully FTPed file` AND contain one of `DENIAL.TXT|NEWORIGIN.TXT|ORIGIN.TXT|Ed.TXT` but NOT `BRRef[20190724202940].txt` or `Ed_20190724_231907.TXT`? is that correct?

Comment: Thats correct Lee.

Comment: I will later be dumping those lines into a new text file and emailing it to myself, but first I need to be able to successfully extract those lines.

Comment: take a look at my answer. [*grin*] it seems to do the job ... if something is unclear, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

presuming that you want *only* the 4 lines that match those 4 path\file names AND have `Successfully FTPed file` in the line, this seems to work. [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
[11:18:24 PM] Begin SFTP File \\BATCH1\TO\BRRef[20190724202940].txt To BRRef.txt
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\DENIAL.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\DENIAL.TXT]
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\NEWORIGIN.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\NEWORIGIN.TXT]
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\ORIGIN.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\ORIGIN.TXT]
[11:18:48 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\BRRef[20190724202940].txt] to [\BRRef.txt]
[11:18:48 PM] Update ProducedFile Set DeliveredFileName='BRRef.txt' Where CreateID=7710395
[11:18:48 PM] Successfully backed up file as :\\BATCH1\TO_BACKUP\BRRef[20190724202940]_20190724_231848.txt
FILE #2. [Ed.TXT[20190724194428]], begin FTP at [11:19:05 PM] 
Destination file name is: Ed.TXT[20190724194428]
After replaceing [], destination file name become: Ed.TXT
[11:19:05 PM] Begin SFTP File \\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT[20190724194428] To Ed.TXT
[11:19:07 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\Ed.TXT]
[11:19:07 PM] Update ProducedFile Set DeliveredFileName='Ed.TXT' Where CreateID=7710363
[11:19:07 PM] Successfully backed up file as :\\BATCH1\TO_BACKUP\Ed_20190724_231907.TXT[20190724194428]
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$TargetOne = 'Successfully FTPed file'
$TargetTwo = @(
    '\\BATCH1\TO\DENIAL.TXT'
    '\\BATCH1\TO\NEWORIGIN.TXT'
    '\\BATCH1\TO\ORIGIN.TXT'
    '\\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT'
    )

<# disabled due to one server with ps3
$T2_Regex = $TargetTwo.ForEach({
    [regex]::Escape($_)
    }) -join '|'
#>
# this pipeline version otta work with ps3
$T2_Regex = ($TargetTwo |
    ForEach-Object {
    [regex]::Escape($_)
        }) -join '|'

$InStuff |
    Where-Object {
        $_ -match $TargetOne -and
        $_ -match $T2_Regex
        }
```

output ...

```
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\DENIAL.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\DENIAL.TXT]
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\NEWORIGIN.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\NEWORIGIN.TXT]
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\ORIGIN.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\ORIGIN.TXT]
[11:19:07 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\Ed.TXT]
```

Comment: foreach($file in $files)
{

 if($file.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString() -gt (get-date).AddDays(-.5))
 {
  #Code Is Here
 }
}

Comment: @salazar44 - what does that have to do with matching patterns in lines of text? i am confused ... [*blush*]

Comment: @lee_daily I guess Im confused how to integrate your code into what I already have done.

Comment: Can you change your example to a Get-Content of a file?  It will help me see/undertand it better.  Thanks.

Comment: use `$InStuff = Get-Content -LiteralPath $FullFileName` ... as my comment at the top of the answer mentioned. [*grin*]

Comment: @salazar44 - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: bummer, when moving this script to the actual server it no longer works.  I guess powershell 3.0 doesnt support the $TargetTwo.ForEach part of your code. Method invocation failed, method not found

Comment: I didnt realize the server had different version.  My bad!

Comment: @salazar44 - ah! then i can change that to use the pipeline. wait about 10 minutes & i will have a new version up ... [*grin*]

Comment: @salazar44 - try the new version - it should work with ps3 ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

It my be more prudent for you to do this via RegEx matches.

For example: Using a RegEx for multiple matches based on a simple pattern match

```
Clear-Host

$MyString = @'
[11:18:24 PM] Begin SFTP File \\BATCH1\TO\BRRef[20190724202940].txt To BRRef.txt
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\DENIAL.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\DENIAL.TXT]
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\NEWORIGIN.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\NEWORIGIN.TXT]
[11:18:44 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\ORIGIN.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\ORIGIN.TXT]
[11:18:48 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\BRRef[20190724202940].txt] to [\BRRef.txt]
[11:18:48 PM] Update ProducedFile Set DeliveredFileName='BRRef.txt' Where CreateID=7710395
[11:18:48 PM] Successfully backed up file as :\\BATCH1\TO_BACKUP\BRRef[20190724202940]_20190724_231848.txt
FILE #2. [Ed.TXT[20190724194428]], begin FTP at [11:19:05 PM] 
Destination file name is: Ed.TXT[20190724194428]
After replaceing [], destination file name become: Ed.TXT
[11:19:05 PM] Begin SFTP File \\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT[20190724194428] To Ed.TXT
[11:19:07 PM] Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT[20190724194428]] to [\Ed.TXT]
[11:19:07 PM] Update ProducedFile Set DeliveredFileName='Ed.TXT' Where CreateID=7710363
[11:19:07 PM] Successfully backed up file as :\\BATCH1\TO_BACKUP\Ed_20190724_231907.TXT[20190724194428]
'@ 

$MyRegExMatch = 'Successfully FTPed.*?TXT'
([regex]::Matches($MyString,$MyRegExMatch).Value)

# Results

<#
Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\DENIAL.TXT
Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\NEWORIGIN.TXT
Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\ORIGIN.TXT
Successfully FTPed file [\\BATCH1\TO\Ed.TXT
#>
```

Or

```
Clear-Host
$MyRegExMatch = 'Successfully FTPed.*?TXT'
Get-Content -Path 'variable:\MyString' | 
ForEach {([regex]::Matches($MyString,$MyRegExMatch).Value)}
```

Comment: i'm confused [*blush*] - why doesn't your regex match this one `[\\BATCH1\TO\BRRef[20190724202940].txt]`? it looks like it otta match that line.

Comment: @Postanote, this doesnt appear to filter only the 4 items I specified.

Comment: @lee_Dailey, you are right.  the regex will return all lines containing 'Successfully FTPed'

Comment: @salazar44 - thank you for the confirmation! [*grin*]

Comment: As for this 'this doesnt appear to filter only the 4 items I specified.'  but that is what my results are showing you. So, I am not sure what you mean, I guess. That is an actual run and only 4 results are given.

Comment: Lee, as for 'why doesn't your regex match this one [\\BATCH1\TO\BRRef[20190724202940].txt]? '... no it should not, because, it's not a match... [\\BATCH1\TO\BRRef[20190724202940].txt]... if it were this... \\BATCH1\TO\BRRef.TXT[20190724202940]], then it would match and shows in the list. Remember RegEx is case sensitive by design.

Comment: As for this... 'you are right. the regex will return all lines containing 'Successfully FTPed' … no, it does not. It can't. Again, RegEx is case sensitive, so it's impossible for it to return all, as written.